# intersection between 2 range sets

Tags: ruby

How can I do range interceptions in ruby ?

Like this:

```
[-4, 3] intersection [-2, 5] = [-2, 3]
[10, 20] intersection [5, 10] = [10]
[-10, -5] intersection [-8, -3] = [-8,-5]
[-5, -3] intersection [2, 20] = nil
```

Comment: `[-4, 3]` is an *array*, a *range* looks like this: `(-4..3)`

Comment: And a [`Set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) is something else.

Comment: And the expressions are illicit.

Comment: And please use English punctuation when you write in English.

Comment: And what is "range interception"?

Comment: Have you tried surface-to-range missiles?

Comment: To stem downvotes and votes to close (and maybe getting some retracted), edit to change "interceptions" to "intersections" and, for example, change your first example to `(-4..3).intersection -2..5 #=> -2..3`. I also suggest you use the term "overlap" rather than "intersection", assuming that is what you mean. If you are not amused by all the previous comments, you should be. Life is too short to worry about little missteps while you're learning something new.

Answer (score 2):

```
def foo((a, b), (c, d))
  min, max = [a, c].max, [b, d].min
  case min <=> max
  when -1 then [min, max]
  when 0 then [min]
  when 1 then nil
  end
end

foo([-4, 3], [-2, 5]) # => [-2, 3]
foo([10, 20], [5, 10]) # => [10]
foo([-10, -5], [-8, -3]) # => [-8, -5]
foo([-5, -3], [2, 20]) # => nil
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Range
  def range_overlap(other)
    [self.min, other.min].max..[self.max, other.max].min
  end
end

(-4..3  ).range_overlap -2..5  #=> -2..3
(10..20 ).range_overlap 5..10  #=> 10..10
(-10..-5).range_overlap -8..-3 #=> -8..-5
(-5..-3 ).range_overlap -2..20 #=> -2..-3 
(1..4   ).range_overlap 2..3   #=> 2..3
```

`r.first > r.last`, as in `r = -2..-3`, indicates there is no overlap. If you'd prefer `nil` to be returned in that case, use

```
r = ([self.min, other.min].max)..([self.max, other.max].min)
r.last >= r.first ? r : nil
```

I've also returned `[10,10]` rather than, say, `10` (certainly not `[10]`) because I think it would make your subsequent code easier to write. (It's analogous to a method returning `[[1,2], [3], [4,5]]` instead of `[[1,2], 3, [4,5]]`.)

I think it probably would be best to always return `Range` objects. That permits subsequent code to be written, for example:

```
r = range_overlap(other)
case r.first <=> r.last
  when 1 # r.first > r.last
     <put out the trash>
  when 0 # r.first == r.last
     <let the cat out>
  else   # r.first < r.last
     <go to a movie>
end
```

Comment: Just a note: this doesn't work with infinite ranges (like `0..`). You'd need to ask the `.begin` and `.end` instead of `.min` and `.max`. And you'd need some additional nil guards to protect against errors being thrown in the `min` and `max` functions.

Comment: This should be a solution that works with infinite ranges:

`[self.begin, other.begin].compact.max..[self.end, other.end].compact.min`

Comment: @sanderd17, I don't think Ruby had (e.g.) `0..` when this was written, and it does work with `+-Float::INFINITY`, so I'll leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = [-4, 3]
s = [-2, 5]
inter = [[f[0],s[0]].max, [f[1],s[2]].min].uniq
inter = nil if inter[1] && inter[1] < inter[0]
```

Comment: Or, `inter = nil unless inter.sort == inter`.